# Однокоренные ли слова?

Tags: этимология

Очень интересно находить однокоренные слова, обозначающие сейчас совершенно разные понятия. Вот, например, являются ли однокоренными словам "улица" и "улитка"?

Comment: В современном языке точно нет. А про этимологию - скоро присоединится behemothus и все расскажет, или olsa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Слово **улитка** образовано с пом, уменьш. суф. -к-а от сущ. *улита*,которое некогда, вероятно, значило нечто вроде «владетель дупла» (раковины), «снабженный убежищем, дуплом». Сущ. *улита* является производным с суф. -ит- от праслав. *ul- (*ula) «дупло».

Слово **улица** образовано с помощью суф. -иц-а (как граница)от сущ. *ула* «улица» с тем же корнем -ул-, что в слове *улей*. Первонач. оно значило «дыра,отверстие», откуда дальнейшее «вход, ворота» > «проход» > «проход между рядами домов».

Таким образом, слова **улитка** и **улица**, действительно имеют общее происхождение. Сюда же и слово **улей**. (По словарям Фасмера, Цыганенко)

Answer (score 4):

Слова, видимо, родственны на праславянском уровне.
Хотя нынешнее фонетическое сходство - результат совершенно разных процессов.
Оба слова (улица - достоверно, улитка - предположительно) восходят к праславянскому морфу ul- c общим значением "пустой", "полый", отсюда же "улей".
Улица первоночально означала немощеная, "пустая дорога", а также дол, овраг и т.п. - все протяженное и "пустое".
А вот "улитка" видимо от прелагателього со значением "пустой (дом)", т.е. полый, короче -раковина. Хотя тут можно только предполагать.